# Question about Polar Coordinates and Constant Values

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, volume

My questions pertains to why the following limits of integration would be the following given the following scenario:\begin{equation}\int_0^a \int_0^\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \frac{dy\ dx}{(1+x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}2} \end{equation}
I have to convert it to polar coordinates and solve it, I got this as my as my region:
\begin{equation}\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 \int_0^\sqrt{a} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dr d\theta \end{equation}
But my region is supposed to be this:
\begin{equation}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^a \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^\frac{3}2}dr d\theta\end{equation}

Any thoughts to why is it particularly that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \implies x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is the equation of a circle of radius $|a|$ centered at the origin. Since the original equation has $x$ going from $0$ to $a$, I'll assume that $a \gt 0$ so $|a| = a$. Thus, with $y$ going from $0$ to $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ and $x$ going from $0$ to $a$, this would be the portion of the circle in the first quadrant. As such, $r$ would go from $0$ to $a$.

Comment: Thank thank you very much I was confused because I thought I had to take the square root of it.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky You're welcome. You're right to take the square root, but since there's an $a^2$, the square root is $a$. However, if the equation was instead something like $x^2 + y^2 = b$ for some $b \gt 0$, so the upper limit for $y$ was then $\sqrt{b - x^2}$, you would have that in polar coordinates the upper limit for $r$ would then be $\sqrt{b}$.